# Jquery Hiding tags within the body

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" >
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").click(function()
{
   callMe();
});


function callMe()
{

$("body .p").hide();
}

});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<h2>This is a heading2</h2>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi ,

I am new to Jquery , so please excuse if my questions are dumb .
Here i am trying to hide the P tags within the body ( On click of that submit button )

But this is no working .

could anybody please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the function to

```
function callMe()
{
    $("body p").hide();
}
```

Your mistake was here:

The `.p` means any tag with a css-class named `p`, nor a `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

`$("body .p").hide();` //This is wrong

try

```
$("body p").hide();
```

or simply

```
$("p").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

. is used for a class. So do not use .p that would signify elements with class name p. Since p is your element you can simply use ("body p")

Answer (score 0):

Be careful!
`$("body p").hide()` will hide every single `<p>` inside your body include `<p>`s inside your header and/or footer and/or everywhere else! It's better you place your `<p>`s -which you want to hide- inside particular `<div>`s and use `$(".hiding_divs p").hide()`.

Comment: Adding additional divs seems a bit over the top if you can just add a class to every p which should be hidden and then use `$('p.hideMe')` as selector. But both ways will work!